# How can I loop through Windows Services and compare them with an text file in batch

Tags: batch-file

I did a batch code which is a security check, to see if any system services have been modified.

This works through a previously registered text file, which contains the name of each Windows service.

```
AJRouter
ALG
AppIDSvc
Appinfo
AppReadiness
AppXSvc
AudioEndpointBuilder
Audiosrv
autotimesvc
AxInstSV
BDESVC
BFE
BITS
...
```

I managed to do the part where the code loops on each line of the text file, and checks if any Windows services are missing.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (WindowsServices.txt) do (
    SC QUERY %%A > NUL
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1060 (ECHO %%A IS MISSING)
)

PAUSE
```

I would also like my code to check if there is any new service that is not registered in the text file. After a few attempts, I couldn't find a way to make my idea work. How can I do this?

Comment: to give you a start: `for /f "tokens=1*" %a in ('sc query ^|find "SERVICE_NAME"') do @echo %b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

(   for /f "tokens=1,*" %%A in (
        'sc query type^= service type^= userservice state^= all ^| find "SERVICE_NAME:"'
    ) do @echo %%B
) > all.tmp

(   for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (
        'findstr /b /e /i /l /v /g:"WindowsServices.txt" "all.tmp"'
    ) do @echo + %%A

    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (
        'findstr /b /e /i /l /v /g:"all.tmp" "WindowsServices.txt"'
    ) do @echo - %%A

    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (
        'findstr /b /e /i /l /g:"all.tmp" "WindowsServices.txt"'
    ) do @echo   %%A
) > report.txt

del all.tmp
sort /+3 report.txt /o report.txt
type report.txt
```

Using an output format that maybe easier to read and easier to process with a script if you want to further processing with the output.

Output interpret as:

- If leads with `+`, needs adding to WindowsServices.txt i.e. New.
- If leads with `-`, is in WindowsServices.txt though not in registry i.e. Missing.
- If leads with space, is in WindowsServices.txt and in registry i.e. Good.

If the last item listed is not wanted i.e. Good, then remove the last `for` loop. I added it for completeness so that all service names are accounted for.

`findstr` uses:

- `/b` Matches pattern if at the beginning of a line.
- `/e` Matches pattern if at the end of a line.
- `/i` Specifies that the search is not to be case-sensitive.
- `/l` Uses search strings literally.
- `/g` Get search strings from the specified file.

`sort` gets all the service names in alphabetical order.

Note: Earlier Windows OSes may not have a `userservice` type for `sc.exe`, such as Windows 7. The code works on Windows 10 without modification.

Comment: Your code works fine, but I do not why, it gives wrong information on the three checks that it does.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hwogkowp2vu0au/Print.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for the image, it helps to recognize what is needed. Added some arguments to `sc.exe` to match services in the image. Without extra arguments, `sc.exe` was outputting only running `services` and not any of the `userservices`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It's working perfectly. You even did everything even better than I could've ever done haha.